# Detect "out-of-designated-usage" (accessing other arrays memory) in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, realloc

On ARM (Raspbian), I'm receiving `SIGABRT` with my application. From `gdb`'s backtrace I extract (mainly) the error message: `realloc(): invalid next size`.

The data structure of the program is quite complicated, but may be understood (very simplified) as several arrays of structs (members with different types) allocated directly one after another (and later dynamically resized on demand using `realloc()`).

I think (correct me if you think I'm mistaken) that the error comes due to the fact that a part of the code is writing out of bounds of one of the arrays. However, by chance, the memory it writes to is allocated **for a different** array. Hence, the code does not receive `SIGSEGV`.

`array1` has been allocated to have 1000 members.
`array2` has been allocated directly afterwards to also hold 1000 members.

Using `gdb`, I can do the following:

```
(gdb) print array1[999]
$1 = {count = 0, blockedcount = 0, domain = 0x0, wildcard = false}
(gdb) print array1[1000]
$2 = {count = 0, blockedcount = 249, domain = 0x166 <error: Cannot access memory at address 0x166>, wildcard = 32}
(gdb) print array1[1001]
$10 = {count = 1420597384, blockedcount = 1015, domain = 0x54acf6a0 "192.168.2.157", wildcard = 200}
```

As can be seen, the array can be accessed at `1000` and beyond, although this memory was **never** allocated for `array1`, but for `array2` (having slightly different internal data types):

```
(gdb) print &array1[999]
$3 = (array1DataStruct *) 0x54acf170
(gdb) print &array1[1000]
$4 = (array1DataStruct *) 0x54acf180
(gdb) print &array2[0]
$5 = (array2DataStruct *) 0x54acf188
(gdb) print &array1[1001]
$6 = (array1DataStruct *) 0x54acf190
```

to see that through too large indices of `array1` I can (foolishly) access memory in `array2`.

**Question:**

Is there an elegant way to detect "out-of-array-bounds" but "inside-allocated-memory-by-the-whole-program" accesses error using some simple measure (like a compiler flag like `-fsanitize=address`)?

Unfortunately, it seems like `valgrind` isn't capable of doing proper analysis on ARMv6 hardware:

```
disInstr(arm): unhandled instruction: 0xF1010200
                 cond=15(0xF) 27:20=16(0x10) 4:4=0 3:0=0(0x0)
==6318== valgrind: Unrecognised instruction at address 0x48426f4.
==6318==    at 0x48426F4: ??? (in /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem.so)
==6318== Your program just tried to execute an instruction that Valgrind
==6318== did not recognise.  There are two possible reasons for this.
==6318== 1. Your program has a bug and erroneously jumped to a non-code
==6318==    location.  If you are running Memcheck and you just saw a
==6318==    warning about a bad jump, it's probably your program's fault.
==6318== 2. The instruction is legitimate but Valgrind doesn't handle it,
==6318==    i.e. it's Valgrind's fault.  If you think this is the case or
==6318==    you are not sure, please let us know and we'll try to fix it.
==6318== Either way, Valgrind will now raise a SIGILL signal which will
==6318== probably kill your program.
==6318== 
==6318== Process terminating with default action of signal 4 (SIGILL)
==6318==  Illegal opcode at address 0x48426F4
==6318==    at 0x48426F4: ??? (in /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem.so)
```

Comment: `Is there an elegant way to detect "out-of-array-bounds" but "inside-allocated-memory-by-the-whole-program"` Short answer :no.

Comment: NO. otherwise there is no need to create efence

Comment: Can't you compile and run it on intel with valgrind for debugging purposes?

Comment: @Ctx The error does not seem to show up on x86_64 hardware